# FFMPEG recombine a video with its original uncropped version

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a video which I cropped to run through a script to process these files much quicker. I would like to now combine the cropped videos back in with their original uncropped version, using the audio from one of the files (the cropped one in this case). The script to crop was:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1000:1000:580:0" -crf 20 -preset slow smaller.mp4
```

So how do I remerge them?

Comment: you can use the `overlay` filter to "uncrop" by placing the frame of `smaller.mp4` at `(580,0)` of `file.mp4`.

Comment: thanks, with overlay what happens with the cropped video if it is shorter, does it show the last frame or "disappear" after it's final timestamp and show just the uncropped video

Comment: depends on the `eof_action` option